# How to insert \r with Visual Studio Regex find-replace

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I would expect that to do a regex find-replace where you'd like to insert one backslash and one lowercase r you would type into the little regex replace box in visual studio `\\r`
[image: backslashbackslashr]

in order to have one escaped backslash and then a lowercase r. However, it doesn't work that way. When you type `\\r` you get *two* backslashes instead of one backslash. And I know what you're thinking - if you type `\r`:

[image]

you get a literal carriage return! How are you supposed to do it?

Comment: It looks like a bug in VS 2017. I would replace it wit, say, `\CR` in the first pass, and then replace `\CR` with `\r` on a second non-regex pass.

Comment: Maybe open the source file in an application such as Notepad++, perform replacements, then reopen in VS.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, to replace `foo` with a literal `\r`, turn off Use Regular Expressions in the Find/Replace box.

[image]

Comment: foo was just a placeholder name, I was wondering how to do it with a regex find-replace